# How to solve Job.Worker 6 (23): EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i launch Unity game in IOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When I run a Unity game on an IOS simulator in Xcode 14.2, I get the following error when starting the game: Job.Worker 6 (23): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x175001000)[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjmPk.jpg)

The Xcode project was built in Unity version 2021.3.16f1 LTS.

With other projects and, accordingly, games, such a problem did not arise.

I tried to change versions of the Unity editor

Comment: is this only happening on simulator and works for devices ?

Comment: I can’t check on a real IOS device due to its absence

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it is difficult to know exactly what is going on, but based on the screen shot, my first thought would be how you are handling concurrency within your app. Look at your threading model and review concurrency in the Swift docs.

[Swift Concurrency Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html)

Comment: The Swift documentation can't help me in any way, since the game is generally written in C#, and the Xcode project contains C/C++ code